# How to avoid exception EXC_RESOURCE - WAKEUPS?

Tags: ios, xcode

In my iPad app I often get a crash report with the exception `EXC_RESOURCE` and the subtype `WAKEUPS`. 
However the strange thing is that the message says `(Limit 150/sec) Observed 0/sec over 300 sec`

How can it become an exception when it observed 0 wakeups/sec? - and how do I avoid it?

The reason I care is that the generation of the report delays some time critical threads in the app. 
Mainly are we recording from the microphone and playing audio at the same time, and while the report is generated, the audio stutters.

The exception is always triggered by one of 3 threads: Main thread, `AURemoteIO: IOThread` and `com.apple.coreaudio.AQClient`. See fragments of report below:

```
Hardware Model:      iPad2,5
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      debugserver [3109]

Date/Time:           2016-05-18 12:15:59.59 +0200
Launch Time:         2016-05-18 12:11:44.44 +0200
OS Version:          iOS 9.1 (13B143)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_RESOURCE
Exception Subtype: WAKEUPS
Exception Message: (Limit 150/sec) Observed 0/sec over 300 secs
Exception Note:  NON-FATAL CONDITION (this is NOT a crash)
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Attributed:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x25ef8c4e 0x25ef6000 + 11342
1   CoreFoundation                  0x25fab760 0x25ef6000 + 743264
...

Thread 10 name:  AURemoteIO::IOThread
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x382acff0 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x382acdf4 mach_msg + 40
2   AudioToolbox                    0x2544ec50 AURemoteIO::IOThread::Run() + 104
3   AudioToolbox                    0x25452500 AURemoteIO::IOThread::Entry(void*) + 8
4   AudioToolbox                    0x25369fee CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 186
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3836385a _pthread_body + 138
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x383637ce _pthread_start + 110
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38361724 thread_start + 8

...

Thread 12 name:  com.apple.coreaudio.AQClient
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x382acff0 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x382acdf4 mach_msg + 40
2   CoreFoundation                  0x25fad8c4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 136
3   CoreFoundation                  0x25fabc4c __CFRunLoopRun + 1036
4   CoreFoundation                  0x25eff118 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
5   CoreFoundation                  0x25efef04 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
6   AudioToolbox                    0x253810b4 GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 132
7   AudioToolbox                    0x25369fee CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 186
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3836385a _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x383637ce _pthread_start + 110
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38361724 thread_start + 8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main confusion was the `Observed 0/sec` statement, but I found that this number was wrong. When running the same code on a newer and faster iPad it suddenly showed a number here (200-400), so it was simply due to a slow iPad that it could not calculate a number.

Secondly I found that there was indeed a thread that was starting and stopping way too often, but it was *not* the one that triggered the error, so that made it a lot more difficult to locate.